# Django Url not redirecting correctly on user creation

Tags: python, django, url

I have a user sign up and login template set to send information to the same view (detail).  They were both working fine before, however now the redirect on user creation is no longer going to the correct URL (http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/accounts/21/) the "accounts/login?next=" portion of the URL is being added for some reason and I cannot understand where it came from as it was not there before.

I'm using stronghold which makes every view login_required unless noted otherwise with @public above it.

I have found some posts about LOGIN_URL needs to be set in setting.py or a `next` key.  However this was working fine before so I do not think that is the problem.  let me know if you need more code posted and I will put it up.

Thanks,

-the route I want to hit is

```
url(r'^accounts/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail')
```

-my register view is below

```
@public
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmailUserCreationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            playthrough = PlayThrough(user_id=new_user.id)
            playthrough.save()                
            request.session['user_id'] = new_user.id

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/{}/'.format(new_user.id))
    else:
        form = EmailUserCreationForm()

    return render(request, 'dep_server/register.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

-this is he view that is supposed to render the user info

```
def detail(request, user_id): 
    if request.session['user_id'] == int(user_id):
        user = EmailUser.objects.get(id=user_id)
        module_list = ModuleRef.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'dep_server/detail.html', {
            'user': user,
            'module_list': module_list
            })
    else:

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/auth/')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, I was not logging in the user on creation.  Which is why the login worked and the sign up did not. below is the code that I added to the register view, which got it to work.

```
user = authenticate(
                email = form.cleaned_data['email'],
                password = form.cleaned_data['password2']                
                )
            login(request, user)
```